# Entity Framework with Azure SQL Database Returning 0 Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I'm setting up a new application in Azure and I'm using an Azure SQL database. I'm using Entity Framework to connect to it from an ASP.NET MVC application.

My setup is as follows: I have a solution with 2 projects in it. In my one project, I have my Entity Models. This is where I've set up my connection to Entity Frameworks and the models were generated (code first). The other project is my ASP.NET MVC project. This is where I'm calling code from the first project to retrieve data. I'm running the following code from my MVC project:

```
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            var x = db.Table1.FirstOrDefault(); //this is null because nothing in table
        }
```

My config file for the Entity project is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*********" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="data source=MY_DATABASE_HERE.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;user id=MY_USERNAME_HERE;password=MY_PASSWORD_HERE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've removed the sensitive information from it, but I've verified that's right - I don't get a connection error anyway. The only other thing I could think of is that my user is not configured with proper permissions, but I can't find where to check/modify that in the Azure portal.

I'm new to Azure, so I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my setup.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but are you sure there is actually any data in your db? Have you connected with sql srv mgt studio?

Comment: Also, you need tcp: at the beginning of the connection string but the fact you are not seeing a connection error indicates that is not a factor.

Comment: If it's an Azure Web site, you should be able to see the actual connection string being used in the Azure portal - may be worth checking there isn't a transformation going on somewhere.

Comment: @Frans Yes I've checked the data. It exists and I can connect from SQL Server Management Studio and view it.
I checked the connection string in Azure and it matches what I've put in. This is under Security Enabled Connection Strings under Auditing and Security.

Comment: Very odd. I've checked your settings against one of my live sites and it looks about the same. Sorry, no idea what is wrong :(

Comment: @Frans I noticed in my context that the `name=DefaultConnection` was there. So I changed it to match the name of my connection string, but it complained that no connection string was found in the config file. So I changed my connection string to be named DefaultConnection and it gives me the same issue as before - no data.

Comment: I've found something: In my context, if I put `base(_THE ENTIRE CONNECTION STRING_)` instead of `base("name: DefaultConnection")`, it works. So something is wrong with how it's pulling from the config file?

Comment: Very peculiar. It should use what you see in the Azure portal.

Comment: Did you copy the configuration from your entity project to your ASP.net MVC project?  It needs to be in the MVC project for it to be published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary solution for this was to change my `base("name=DefaultConnection")` to instead contain the entire connection string. This allowed a connection, but was obviously not ideal.

Then, I ran a reverse-engineer on my Entity Framework project and it generated a proper connection string for me (including properly fixing the above `base()` setting with it.

[image: Right click on the Entity Framework project]

I'm sure most people won't have to go this route, but I figured I'd post my solution just in case.